# SessionCreatedEvent no longer fires after Spring-Boot 2.7 -> 3 upgrade

Tags: spring, spring-boot, session, events, event-handling

In Spring-Boot 2.7.x, I received the SessionCreatedEvent and SessionDestroyedEvent events. After upgrading to Spring Boot 3.0.x, these events no longer get delivered to my app.  I do still receive the SessionFixationProtectionEvent event though. I'm using Redis for session management. I tried going to Spring Boot 3.1.x but it didn't help.

I have `@EnableRedisHttpSession(flushMode = FlushMode.IMMEDIATE, saveMode = SaveMode.ALWAYS, maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 600)` on my `@Configuration` class.

I have configured the SecurityFilterChain as:

```
return http
    .securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext
        .requireExplicitSave(false)
    )
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).anonymous()
        .requestMatchers("/error", "/favicon.ico").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login", "/assets/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .headers()
        .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
        .xssProtection().and()
    .and()
    .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .permitAll()
    .and()
    .sessionManagement()
        .invalidSessionStrategy(new RestfulApiInvalidSessionStrategy(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**")))
        .invalidSessionUrl("/login")
        .sessionCreationPolicy(IF_REQUIRED)
        .sessionFixation().changeSessionId()
        .maximumSessions(2).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)
            .expiredSessionStrategy(new RestfulApiInvalidSessionStrategy(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**")))
            .expiredUrl("/login?expired")
        .and()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
    .successHandler(this.authenticationSuccessHandler)
    .failureHandler(this.authenticationFailureHandler)
    .and()
    .httpBasic()
    .and()
    .csrf().disable()
    .build()
```

My event listeners are thus:

```
    @EventListener
    public void onSessionCreated(SessionCreatedEvent event) {
        log.info("session created");
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onSessionDestroyed(SessionDestroyedEvent event) {
        log.info("session destroyed");
    }

    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @EventListener(SessionFixationProtectionEvent.class)
    public void onSessionFixationProtectionEvent(SessionFixationProtectionEvent event) {
        log.info("session migrated");
    }
```

I have registered the HttpSessionEventPublisher:

```
    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
```

I'm not sure what else I need to do. It worked in 2.7 but not in 3.0.  I have tried registering a `@WebListener` and listening for HttpSessionEvents but those don't seem to get fired either.

Comment: did you get any clue, on this?

Comment: No. From what I could find, the session events are no longer fired.  The RedisSession repository class changed and the new default class does not fire the events, and trying to wire the old class in caused all sorts of other headaches.  I had to hack something together, it was definitely NOT pretty.

Comment: I have added the solution below, it is working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is support for **spring boot 3.2.0** for this.

Change **`@EnableRedisHttpSession`** to --->**`@EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession`**.
This change will configure **RedisIndexedSessionRepository** over **RedisSessionRepository** .

By using this `RedisIndexedSessionRepository` you can now start to listen to `SessionCreatedEvent`, `SessionDeletedEvent`, `SessionDestroyedEvent` and `SessionExpiredEvent` events.

For detailed explanation visit [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/configuration/redis.html#configuring-redisindexedsessionrepository).
For listening to Session Events visit [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/configuration/redis.html#listening-session-events).

---

And in your session security configuration.

add the below to save the sessions in the repository. Read more about [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#requireexplicitsave)

```
http.securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext
                .requireExplicitSave(false)
        )
```